# How to view phpmyadmin GUI while accessing your AWS EC2 server from terminal?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal, phpmyadmin, amazon-ec2

I have access to my AWS EC2 ubuntu server and have installed php5, mysql, phpmyadmin in it. I have also imported the database but through mac terminal commands only.

Now the problem is, I am more comfortable in using MySql from localhost/phpmyadmin/ like interface rather than terminal commands only. Is there any way I can see/launch the same interface from my terminal which has access to my ubuntu server?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Install phpMyAdmin**

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

To **access phpmyadmin** on `AWS EC2` do the following:

```
http://your_ip_or_domain_name/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: This is great if it works. But in my case I am getting a 404 not found error. What can be the possible reasons?

Comment: have you installed phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes. When I do sudo apt-get install phypmyadmin, there are no new installations. It's already there.

Comment: @DewPar restart the server

Comment: @DewPar how do you access in browser? have you installed mysql?

Comment: I have restarted the server. Plus, the www folder has only html directory which contains my site-static files and no phpmyadmin. In the browser I use the IP address only as of now as I haven't updated the namespace details for IP to point to my domain name.

Comment: have you installed mysql? and phpmyadmin in in /etc/ folder

Comment: Yes. PHP5, MySql, phpmyadmin evrything is there.

Comment: after installing mysql, did you restart server? `service apache2 restart`

Comment: Yes the I have restarted the servers on each installation. And right now also I have done it.

Comment: refer this link: http://www.codetweet.com/apache-2/install-apache2phpmysqlphpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-11-04-lamp-server/

Comment: Hi this didn't help much as commands don't give the full idea to me. Instead I did this : http://jafty.com/blog/installing-phpmyadmin-using-ftp/ And this works the best. Now my-site/phpmyadmin is working well and good!

Comment: @DewPar great and glad to help :)